# Java Array Index Out of Bounds Exception Processing

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Given the following Java codes:

```
int test = createIntData(Column[8]);

private int createIntData (String realData) {
    if (realData == null) {
        return (int) (Math.random()*100); 
    }
    else {
        return Integer.parseInt(realData);
    }
}
```

This throws exception like this：

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

This is because the argument only have an maximum index of 4. Then how to change the program to realize the function that: once the argument is out of index, return the value:

```
Math.random() * 100
```

Comment: The problem is in `Column[8]`. It's got nothing to do with your `createIntData` method, really. The argument is evaluated before the method gets called - so if evaluating the argument fails (as it is doing here), there's nothing the method can do about it.

Comment: @JonSkeet `Column[8]` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10` doesn't fit

Comment: Then how to verify the Column[8] first and do sth with it if it is out of index?@JonSkeet

Comment: Forget about the number '10', because I do not make a full copy of my codes. @TAsk

Comment: In Java, naming conventions dictate that variables begin with a lower case letter.  This makes it easier to quickly tell the difference between types and variables.  You can see by SME_Dev's answer that not following this convention can really throw people off.

Comment: I think the answers already solve my confusion~ @TAsk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with allowing for check inside the method, by passing array and index:

```
public int createIntData(String[] values, int index) {
    if (values != null && index >= 0 && index < values.length) {
        return Integer.parseInt(values[index]);
    }
    return (int) (Math.random()*100);
}
```

Call it:

```
int test = createIntData(Column, 8);
```

This way the method can safely be called with any input (I left the potential exception in the parseInt, though)

Comment: `realData` should be `values[index]`.

Answer (score 1):

If `8` is outside the range of `Column`'s length, that error is what you get. Change this

```
int test = createIntData(Column[8]);
```

to (using the [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java))

```
int test = createIntData((8 < Column.length) ? Column[8] : null);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 severe problems:

1.You should check, whether a given array index does exist:

```
Column[] array = new Column[someCapacity];
//fill the array

int i = 8;

if( i < array.length && i > -1 ){
    int test = createIntData(array[i]);
}
```

2.The array's type(`Column`) does not match the `createIntData()` input parameter (`String`)